# pjsua calls fail

Tags: sip, voip, pjsip

I'm facing a problem with calls using pjsua. Registration on server is always successful, but most of the time I try to call to my cell phone, state of call stands CALLING for ever and nothing is really happening or I get error 406 (not acceptable). Just in few cases (ca 1 of 20) was the call successful.
When I try to call using softphone from provider, everything is OK. However, I need command line interface for my work.

These are the information I obtained from my sip provider:

```
SIP port: 5060
Proxy: viphone.sk
Use Outbound Proxy: yes
Outbound Proxy: sip.break.viphone.sk
Register: yes
User ID: AAAAA
User Auth ID: YES
Password: Authenticate Password: XXXXX
Auth ID: AAAAA
Prefered Codec: G729a
Use Prefered Codec Only: no
```

And these are otption used when starting pjsua:

```
--registrar  sip:viphone.sk
--id         sip:AAAAA@viphone.sk
--proxy      sip:viphone.sk;lr
--outbound   sip:sip.break.viphone.sk;lr
--realm      *
--username   AAAAA
--password   XXXXX
```

I'm running pjsua like this:
pjsua --config-file conf sip:myMobNumber@viphone.sk

Is there something wrong or missing in my configuration?

Comment: A few points; Firstly: --registrar should be sip.break.viphone.sk. Secondly: StackOverflow is not the place for this question, try SuperUser or ServerFault. Thirdly; I use pjsua and I am having problems with it witholding the caller ID, perhaps the calls are blocked when originating from pjsua and not a softphone because your  carrier doesn't allow you to withhold the number?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add the option `--no-tcp` to the configuration, which avoids using TCP. I am not sure why it even tries, because it should use UDP by default anyway...

Hope this helps!

DISCLAIMER:
I know this is an old post, and that it probably shouldn't belong here,
but I have been searching for the same answer for some time, and there are not many resources out there. This one keeps showing up on google searches, so it might really be helpful for someone.